# Documents showing that another person can pay for your visit - UK VISA

Tags: visas, uk

I am an Indian citizen, applying for UK visa from India.

In document checklist for UK Visa there is the following column

> Documents showing that another person can pay for your visit, such as : Bank statements of the person paying for your visit

I am being paid by my institute to attend a conference. Host institute is providing accommodation.

What should i attach in this case?

Comment: Are you doing any sort of activities at that conference?  That may require a visa *other than* the standard tourist visa.  In that case, the institute would be involved owing to the visa type.

Comment: I do not understand what does it mean to say “any sort of activities”. @Harper

Comment: The invitation letter you received should say that they are paying for your expenses.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes, it says they are paying for my accommodation... my institute is paying for travel and remaining things

Comment: OK, can your institute give you a document saying you are going to the conference and they are paying for the travel and incidental expenses?

Comment: Yes it has already given that @MichaelHampton